# Using Postgresql Schemas with Sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to drop all tables in a schema (Postgres 9.3). When the models were being created, I have specified which schema they belong to.

```
model.schema( "schema_name")
```

And I was able to generate all tables in this specific schema. No problem here. However, when I want to drop the tables in the same schema, I am having to explicitly set the search path for it to be successful.

```
        db.sequelize.query("set search_path=consumer")
        .then( function( arg ){
            db.sequelize.drop({cascade:true})
                .then( function( arg ){
                    fulfill( arg );
                },function( err ){
                    reject( err );
                });
        });
```

When Sequelize claims support for PostgreSQL schema, I would expect that this detail must have been taken care of (because most of the other features work charmingly well!). So my question is : Do I have to set search path or am I missing some option that I am not making use of?

Answer (score 2):

sequelize creates a clone of the object, sets the schema on it and returns the clone.  Therefore the original object is unchanged.

Try 
`model.schema( "schema_name")` instead.